# An error message is telling me a method is undefined but it appears to be defined

Tags: java, methods, undefined

This is the driver class which includes the method which receives the error message, "The method ReadSongArray(File, int) is undefined for the type SongArray." I'm not sure what's going wrong here because I made sure to create an object of type SongArray in my driver class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ArrayDriver {

    public void main(String[] args){
        File file1 = new File("TenKsongs.csv");
        SongArray drive = new SongArray();
        drive.ReadSongArray(file1, 10);
    }
}
```

Here is the SongArray class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SongArray {

public Song[] ReadSongArray(File file, int numsongs){
    File file1=new File("TenKsongs.csv");
    Song[] songDB;
    songDB=new Song[numsongs];
    int i=0;
    try{
        FileReader file_reader=new FileReader(file1);
        BufferedReader buf_reader = new BufferedReader (file_reader);
        while(i<numsongs){
            String line=buf_reader.readLine();
            String[] data=line.split(",");// in csv file, attributes are separate using ","
            //transfer string to float and int
            float duration_StrF=Float.parseFloat(data[3]);
            int digitalid_StrInt=Integer.parseInt(data[4]);

            String title_rmSP=data[1].replaceAll("\\s+", "");//remove spaces in song title and artist name
            String artist_rmSP=data[2].replaceAll("\\s+", "");


            Song chips = new Song(title_rmSP,artist_rmSP,duration_StrF,digitalid_StrInt);

            i++;
        }
        buf_reader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (songDB);
}

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason your `main()` is not static?

Comment: Good catch. However, this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Try to Clean and Rebuild your project (or manually delete the class files and then compile again). Also make sure you don't have another class named SongArray (also I'm assuming these are in the same package/directory?)

Comment: I just noticed this, and I don't know if its what's causing your problem or not. You should either have a try/catch around the File creation, or have your main method throw the FileNotFound exception I believe, unless I'm being silly and those don't need an exception.

Comment: @Darren I don't think they do. The File object is just a handle to the file, where you really need checks is when the file is opened with a reader/writer, which the code does have.

Comment: Where is your constructor in the SongArray class to create an instance?  Are you extending another class?  Because right now you only have a function within your SongArray class.  Whereas a method must be performed on an instance of an object.  Unless SongArray is supposed to be static...

Comment: Should I add something like SongArray a = new SongArray(); to my SongArray class?

Comment: Is there anymore to your SongArray class than what you posted in your question?  If so, can you post the rest of it?

Comment: This is the whole class.

Comment: I'm not extending another class and SongArray isn't supposed to be static.

Comment: Wrote you an answer.  You're missing some parts to your class.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an old version of the class that doesn't have that method in the classpath. Try saving the source code file, recompile, redeploy, and restart the server.

It's things like this that will drive a developer mad.

Comment: I just did a Clean and Rebuild and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is because your `SongArray` class is missing a few components if you are going to make it an object instance.  You should read up on Object Oriented Programming, but by calling `new SongArray()` is telling Java to create an instance of `SongArray`  You need to add a constructor to your class to do this, unless you are making a `static` class that you do not create an instance of, but instead pass parameters to it with never calling new.

```
public class SongArray
{
    //public or private components
    private Song[] songDB;
    private int i;

     //default constructor 
    public SongArray()
     {
        //build components of the SongArray object such as:
        songDB = new Song[100];
     }
     //overloaded constructor
     public SongArray(int count, Song[] songs)
     {
          songDB = songs;
          i = count;
    }
    //other components of class and various functions such as:
    public Song[] readSongArray(File f, int numsong)
    {
        //do stuff here like in your question
    }

}
```

You should create static classes if you do not want to or cannot instantiate them.

You can learn more about OOP from Java/Oracle directly here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: I added this to my SongArray class because I think that's what you were telling me to do. I am not as fluent in java as I would like to be. But I'm still missing something. I'm pretty lost right now.   public SongArray(File file, int numsongs){
  this.file = file;
  this.numsongs = numsongs;
 }

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but you really need to learn more of the basics of java and oop before you continue.  What you just wrote there is part of a constructor.  This creates the object based on the parameters you sent (file and numsongs).

Comment: No problem.  I think that link will help you create the entire class.  Then in your Driver app you can create it (`new SongArray()`) and call your `ReadSongArray()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is make sure all your classes are in the same package to avoid namespace confusions.

Create a new package
 
eg. com.test.mike

Copy all your files into this package. So that they will referenced as follows on your class path.
 com.test.mike.SongArray 
 com.test.mike.ArrayDriver 
 com.test.mike.Song